# Get resource name of android views programatically

Tags: android, multilingual, android-resources

How can I get the string name of any view's

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/topUpMoney_confirmButton"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    ...(further more child views)

</LinearLayout>
```

Lets say above TextView has the **text = "Transfer my Amount**" and it is located in the string resources file under the name "**transfer**", 
I want to get the name "transfer" from the above view not the value programatcially.

> note: I may or may not have ids for all the views, I just want to know if the view has text loaded from string.xml, and if yes then what is the name?

Since there may be lots of child views inside the View Group I may not know. So I planed to loop through all the children views inside ViewGroup, get the string used on that view and override the text with different string value(locale) which have the name "transfer" in this case.

I am trying this for Multilanguage .

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch it like this

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytxt); 
String resourceName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.id.mytxt);
```

Comment: No I may not have any ids on the view, I just want to know if the view has text loaded from string.xml, if yes then what is the name of string

Answer (score 0):

Try this out Kotlin Version

```
var yourRootView = viewDataBinding?.editProfileRoot  //Your Root View
        var childCount = yourRootView?.childCount //This will get childCount of your rootview
        for (i in 0..childCount!!) {
            var textViewValue = ""
            var childView = yourRootView?.getChildAt(i) //Getting view from that index
            if (childView is TextView) { //Checking whether view is TextView
                if (yourRootView != null) {
                    childView = yourRootView.getChildAt(childCount) as TextView //Converting view as TextView
                    textViewValue = childView.text.toString() //Getting value from that view
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry bro. I am not asking for the value of view, but I am trying to get the name of the string if the  text is set from string.xml

Comment: U can get int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "string", getPackageName());
textview.setText(resID);